# Setting values in QPolygonF

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to set a value in a QPolygonF object to a certain value. For example:

```
QPolygonF *polygonPoints;
polygonPoints->resize(2);
polygonPoints[1] = QPointF(5.0,5.0);
```

When I try to compile I get an error which says there is no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'QPointF'. QPolygon is inherited from QVector so I feel this should work... The above code works when I use "<<" but I'd like to modify specific values in the polygon instead of just appending values. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please include the full error message and fix your code (replace `QPolygon` by `QPolygonF` and `->` by `.`).

Comment: This is strange, when I do qDebug << polygonPoints[0] it returns the entire contents of the array in the terminal instead of the entry at index 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QPolygonF` (and all the other Qt containers) are best used without pointers or else you'll need to dereference the pointer:

```
(*polygonPoints)[1] = QPointF(5.0,5.0);
```

Comment: This is it. Wow. Brackets made the diff. Thanks!